# How to get the stacktrace to show in a log

Tags: python, logging

If I have the following logging formatter:

```
 {"exception": "%(exc_info)s"}'
```

And the following view code:

```
try:
    "2" in None
except TypeError:
    log.error('this is an error')
```

The exception shows up as empty when I look at the log:

```
exception:  "None"
```

How do I get the exception to show up in my logging formatter?

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to specify a custom exception handle

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()

log = logging.getLogger("ASD")
try:
   1/0
except:
   log.exception("I got an error!!!")
```

see : https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/AnimatedHonestDoom

Comment: thanks for this. What's the difference between doing a `log.error` and `log.exception` ?